# res.map() is not a function where res is an Array Object

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

I have data in this form

```
[ 

{ device_id: '12335',
    timestamp: '2018-05-14T08:31:23.000Z',
    temperatur: 21,
    pressure: 31,
    humidity: 20,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  { device_id: '12335',
    timestamp: '2018-05-14T08:31:31.000Z',
    temperatur: 28,
    pressure: 35,
    humidity: 25,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  { device_id: '12335',
    timestamp: '2018-05-14T08:31:33.000Z',
    temperatur: 36,
    pressure: 44,
    humidity: 33,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  { device_id: '12335',
    timestamp: '2018-05-14T08:31:36.000Z',
    temperatur: 31,
    pressure: 39,
    humidity: 30,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  { device_id: '12345',
    timestamp: '2018-05-14T08:31:23.000Z',
    temperatur: 21,
    pressure: 31,
    humidity: 20,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  { device_id: '12345',
    timestamp: '2018-05-14T08:31:31.000Z',
    temperatur: 28,
    pressure: 35,
    humidity: 25,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  { device_id: '12345',
    timestamp: '2018-05-14T08:31:33.000Z',
    temperatur: 36,
    pressure: 44,
    humidity: 33,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  { device_id: '12345',
    timestamp: '2018-05-14T08:31:36.000Z',
    temperatur: 31,
    pressure: 39,
    humidity: 30,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' } ]
```

This is a data which I'm getting back from my sql database. So I used this to store the returned result.

```
var res1 =[];
res1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
```

But now when I'm using map function on this data I'm getting

> res1.map() is not a function.

Why is this happening?

Map function works on all array objects. It was working earlier when I manually copied this data to the variable as `res1=[{..}]`. But now it's not working.

> console.log(result) gives me this

```
[ RowDataPacket {
device_id: '12335',
timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:23.000Z,
temperatur: 21,
pressure: 31,
humidity: 20,
equipment_name: 'truck5' },

  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12335',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:31.000Z,
    temperatur: 28,
    pressure: 35,
    humidity: 25,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12335',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:33.000Z,
    temperatur: 36,
    pressure: 44,
    humidity: 33,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12335',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:36.000Z,
    temperatur: 31,
    pressure: 39,
    humidity: 30,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12345',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:23.000Z,
    temperatur: 21,
    pressure: 31,
    humidity: 20,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12345',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:31.000Z,
    temperatur: 28,
    pressure: 35,
    humidity: 25,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12345',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:33.000Z,
    temperatur: 36,
    pressure: 44,
    humidity: 33,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12345',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:36.000Z,
    temperatur: 31,
    pressure: 39,
    humidity: 30,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' } ]
```

That's why i'm using JSON.stringify().Just using JSON.parse() gives me error.
This is mysql function i'm using

```
db.query(query,
         function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var res1 =[];
    res1=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
  console.log(res1);
  series:[
                res1.map(function(s) {
                    // Meta is only needed if using the tooltip plugin.
                    return {x: s.timestamp, y: s.temperature, meta: s.temperature + ' on ' + s.timestamp.toDateString()};
                })
            ]
 });
```

I'm getting object as the type after using typeof result or res or using it with our without JSON.parse()

Comment: what does `console.log(res1)` give you??

Comment: Why are you stringifying then parsing the result ?

Comment: where does `result` get assigned?

Comment: Can't reproduce. `map` seems to work. [Codepen here](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/RyBwVz?editors=1010)

Comment: @ibowankenobi it gives me the json Object which i have mentioned in the starting

Comment: @JeremyThille no it's not working.I have edited the question.

Comment: @tjadli i have edit the question to clear it out why i'm using JSON.stringify()

Comment: What is the type of `result` as it isn't valid JSON or a JS object?

Comment: @Sloff it is of object type

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` give you?

Comment: @Sloff i have mentioned it in my question under result gives me this

Comment: as @Sloff suggested, console.log(result) and even console.log(typeof result) and console.log(Array.isArray(result))

Comment: @tjadli read the question.i have displayed the result of console.log() under result gives me this and even mentioned that it gives me object type

Comment: @AeshnaKashyap in your question, you are console.log(res1) ! 
i am suggesting to console.log(result), i am trying to understand why you are using res1=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)); instead of res1 = result or res1 = [...result]

Comment: @tjadli i'm getting true as output for console.log(Array.isArray(result))

Comment: @aeshnaKashyap  have you tried res1 = result or res1 = [...result]

Comment: @tjadli i have mentioned what is the result of console.log(result).Under But now its not working.It is the output of console.log(result) not console.log(res1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170997/discussion-between-tjadli-and-aeshna-kashyap).

Answer (score 2):

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) are opposite of each other. If you get a JSON string from your API, you need to use `JSON.parse` to convert it to a JavaScript object (array, in your case).

On the other hand, I don't think `JSON.stringify` will help you much here. Try this:

```
var res1 = JSON.parse(result);
res1.map( ... );
```

To know more about what kind response you receive, you can use `console.log(typeof result)`. If that yields `string` to the console, use `JSON.parse`. If it yields `object`, you don't need to use `JSON.parse` at all.

Comment: JSON.parse() gives me error when i'm using it without JSON.stringify()

Comment: @aeshnaKashyap -- As I mentioned, use `typeof` to identify what kind of response you receive, and then use the appropriate code.

Comment: @31piy You can't actually parse a valide JSON object

Comment: @31piy it gives me object with or without Json.parse()

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON object (well, string...) coming from the server side is malformed. You have made a lot of edits to your post and changed the original response you get from the server. Assuming this is the string you get from the server (calling it 'x') :

```
x = 
"[ RowDataPacket {
device_id: '12335',
timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:23.000Z,
temperatur: 21,
pressure: 31,
humidity: 20,
equipment_name: 'truck5' },

  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12335',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:31.000Z,
    temperatur: 28,
    pressure: 35,
    humidity: 25,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12335',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:33.000Z,
    temperatur: 36,
    pressure: 44,
    humidity: 33,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12335',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:36.000Z,
    temperatur: 31,
    pressure: 39,
    humidity: 30,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12345',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:23.000Z,
    temperatur: 21,
    pressure: 31,
    humidity: 20,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12345',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:31.000Z,
    temperatur: 28,
    pressure: 35,
    humidity: 25,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12345',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:33.000Z,
    temperatur: 36,
    pressure: 44,
    humidity: 33,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' },
  RowDataPacket {
    device_id: '12345',
    timestamp: 2018-05-14T08:31:36.000Z,
    temperatur: 31,
    pressure: 39,
    humidity: 30,
    equipment_name: 'truck5' } ]"
```

and the following parses it without errors:

```
JSON.parse(
    x
    .replace(/timestamp:\s*(.*),/gi,function(m,g1){return 'timestamp: "'+g1+'",'})
    .replace(/RowDataPacket\s*\{|\}\s*(?=,|\s*\])/gi,function(m){return /\}/gi.test(m) ? "}" : "{"})
    .replace(/(?:\w|_)+(?=:)/gi,function(m){return /^\d/gi.test(m) ? m : '"'+m+'"'})
    .replace(/'/gi,'"')
    .replace(/\d+(?=\s*,)/gi,function(m){return '"'+m+'"'})
)
```

this is a very mundane way of fixing the error. It might be better to stringify it from the server side and send it instead.